# How to reload a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, rdata

I've developed a shiny application (using shinydashboard) and i'd like to save the "session" (by session i mean all the values of the input and the data load by the user). I want to save it in a .RData file and then be able to restart the app, load the .RData file and get back the data and the input defined by the user and hence the output...

Is there a way to do such a thing with shiny ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is a `session` object which contains all the inputs and outputs. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried to save the R environment in an .RData file using `save.image`but it did not work out. What worked though is using the `save` and `load` functions to store and restore as .rda files.

As for naming you could use a timestamp maybe to differentiate between users.

## Edit (example)

Okay, so in this app there are two `selectInput` elements: **first**, and **second**. If any of these change, the values of these inputs are then assigned to two variables: **first_var** and **second_var** which are saved to `test.rda` file. If this file exists the variables are loaded into the session.

So basically, if you run the app first, whenever you change the inputs, they are saved into a .rda file. If you exit and then rerun the app, the variables are loaded, and they are set as the selected value of the inputs.

```
library(shiny)
if(file.exists("test.rda")) load("test.rda")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("first",
              label = "First",
              choices = c("Value A", "Value B", "Value C"),
              selected = ifelse(exists("first_var"), first_var, "Value A")
  ),
  selectInput("second",
              label = "Second",
              choices = c("Value D", "Value E", "Value F"),
              selected = ifelse(exists("second_var"), second_var, "Value D")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    first_var <- input$first
    second_var <- input$second
    save(file = "test.rda", list = c("first_var", "second_var"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've try to use the function `save` to save the input into a .RData file, it works, but I didn't manage to restore the input using the 'load' function. How do you do exactly ?

Comment: Save it as .rda.

Something like this if you have 2 variables: `save(file = "test.rda", list = c("first", "second"))`

Then you can load them anytime using `load("test.rda")`.

After loading you will be able to access them. Even in the shiny app. I am adding an example, shortly

Comment: @GyD I know this post is several years old, but I'm trying to do the same thing and just wanted to check, shouldn't the contents of the list that is being saved in the .rda file be unquoted?  e.g. `list = c(first_var, second_var)`? Else if quoted it will save a character vector?

Comment: Actually just answered my own question - I forgot that the function `exists` takes quoted parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Shiny has just released version 0.14, which includes bookmarking that may be a built-in approach to meet your needs.   There is a specific tutorial on "advanced bookmarking" for such purposes as dashboards that would be suitable in your case: 
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html

The 0.14 upgrade requires a current R version (3.3, I think?).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.